# How do I create more than 1 translation for a string in poEdit?

Tags: translation, poedit

I followed this tutorial http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/ where Hello World is translated into German. If I want to translate Hello World to other language. Do I have to create another **message.po** and messge.mo file or I can add another translation in the same file or there's another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you create one .po file per language, and split them up in different directories based on the locale name (like locale/de_DE/ in the tutorial), then you just use the specific file for the chosen locale as text domain in your implementation.